# mysql questions variable

Tags: mysql

I have a web server which is quite heavy on the mysql server:

Here is a graph of questions being executed on the database:

[image: http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/2448/screenshot20120912at101.png]

Is there a way to increase the max questions allowed?  You see how the graph tops off and stays around 5K while the web server is active?

Yes, other things are being done on the code side of things, just wondering what we can do in my.cnf.  All tables are already being served from `/dev/shm`.

Thanks!

Comment: What leads you to believe that the mysql configuration is your bottleneck?  Have you tried running `mysqltunner.pl` for example?  Have you collect any cpu/ram/io stats?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, like I said, other things being done.  Do you know what "questions" graph means?

Comment: a question is pretty much a command run.. so a select/update/delete and so on.. so there is no variable that sets the # of "questions" per minute. You are maxing out somewhere else and need to find that point.

Comment: so that graph is value per minute?  Will investigate! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is a limit set on the number of queries a particular user is able to run per minute, and if your web service logs in to the database using the same user id for all queries, you may be hitting that limit.

Check this page out for more information, it will show you how to check and alter those limits on your system.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-resources.html

Hope it helps!